# Installing docker on centos7: docker-engine-selinux conflicts with docker-selinux-*

Tags: docker, centos7

I tried installing `docker` from yum and from the install script on `Centos7` and both of them give the same error:

`Error: docker-engine-selinux conflicts with docker-selinux-1.10.3-44.el7.centos.x86_64`

I am unable to figure out how to fix this and get docker installed.

Full error traceback:

```
[root@mynode]# wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
/usr/bin/docker: line 13: /usr/bin/docker-latest: No such file or directory
sh: line 149: [: -lt: unary operator expected
sh: line 153: [: -le: unary operator expected
Warning: the "docker" command appears to already exist on this system.

If you already have Docker installed, this script can cause trouble, which is
why we're displaying this warning and provide the opportunity to cancel the
installation.

If you installed the current Docker package using this script and are using it
again to update Docker, you can safely ignore this message.

You may press Ctrl+C now to abort this script.
+ sleep 20
+ sh -c 'sleep 3; yum -y -q install docker-engine'
Error: docker-engine-selinux conflicts with docker-selinux-1.10.3-44.el7.centos.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 9):

```
yum list installed|grep docker
yum remove docker-selinux.x86_64
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Answer (score 1):

If top answer doesn't work, try `yum remove docker-engine-selinux` instead